# How to keep formatting while adding text to a word document with VBA Macros

Tags: vba, formatting, ms-word

I am writing a macro for copying text from a table cell in one document and inserting it in another as plane text. Though the text itself is extracting well, tabs are missing. And I have no clue how to keep formatting not keeping the table around the text.

```
For Each oCell In oRow.Cells

     sCellText = oCell.Range
     sCellText = Left$(sCellText, Len(sCellText) - 2)

     If (RegExp_Script.Test(sCellText) = True) Then

        num1 = RegExp_Script.Replace(sCellText, "$1")
        num2 = RegExp_Script.Replace(sCellText, "$2")

        Set docSingle = Documents.Add
        Selection.TypeText (sCellText)

        docSingle.Range.Find.Execute Findtext:="^m", ReplaceWith:=""

        strNewFileName = Replace(docMultiple.FullName, ".doc", "-e" & num1 & "_" & num2 & ".doc")
        docSingle.SaveAs strNewFileName 'save the new single-paged document

        docSingle.Close

    End If

  Next oCell
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Irene. Could you add comments to your code sample, please, so that we can better understand what needs to be happening? I'm a bit confused by the RegExp_Script lines you have - that's not a Word object so it's not clear what it's doing. May we assume the TAB characters to which you refer are part of the cell content? FWIW the .Text property picks up ONLY plain text, no formatting; and TypeText puts in plain text, only. In order to get the formatting you'd need to use the FormattedText property on both sides of the equation. Something like rngTarget.FormattedText = rngSource.FormattedText

Comment: @CindyMeister I have not had issues with the `TypeText` property deleting Tabs that are part of the string. @Irene do you mean that you want the Inserted Text to have the same paragraph position as when it was in the Table? Eg in the Table is was roughly an indent of 10cm from the Page Margin and you no want it to be pasted with that same indent?

Comment: @Jean-Pierre: It seems you're interpreting the question differently than I... Of course, having not seen the document it's not possible to be sure these are Tabs or Indents (or Indents that were created by pressing Tab + AutoFormat triggering). It's also unclear whether formatting refers only to the "tabs" or to other things, as well...

Comment: 100% correct Cindy.Will have to wait for @"Irene" reply.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your contribution, @CindyMeister , @Jean-Pierre .
I was talking about indents, created by pressing Tab, sorry for inaccuracy.
Also already solved this issue in a different way: extracted not the text from a table cell, by the very cell and removed the table borders after copying it to the new document.
Like that:

```
oCell.Range.Copy 'copy the page into the Windows clipboard
Set docSingle = Documents.Add 'create a new document           
docSingle.Range.Paste 'paste the clipboard contents to the new document
Dim oTable As Word.Table
For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    oTable.Rows.ConvertToText Separator:=wdSeparateByParagraphs, _
    NestedTables:=True
```